# How can I enlarge the toolbar icon in pycharm 2019

Tags: pycharm

I previously use pycharm 2017.3.4, and the toolbar icon size is suitable for me, such as

[image: Original Toolbar]

but when I update to 2019.1.1, the icon becomes like this

[image: New Toolbar]

It's too small for me, I wonder how can I enlarge the toolbar icon, much appreciation!

Comment: If this is a regression that happens with DPI scaling, you should simply report it to Jetbrains.

Comment: um...I don't think it's a scaling issue, maybe Jetbrains change the icon size in the new version